# Using "auto" keyword for std::list iterator with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am writing C++ app which should be compiled both using MS C++ on Windows and GCC on Linux.I wrote a loop on Windows which iterates through std::list:

```
 auto  iter = container.GetObj()->begin();
 while (iter!=container.GetObj()->end()){

   (*(iter++))->Execute();

 }
```

It works fine ,but when compiling it with GCC "auto" gets not recognized:

**Unexptected token "auto"**  (in NetBeans IDE)

So I fixed it defining the iterator "explicitly :

```
 std::list<Container*>::iterator iter=container.GetObj()->begin();
 while (iter!=container.GetObj()->end()){

   (*(iter++))->Execute();

 }
```

**My GCC version is 4.7.2**

Does it mean that GCC doesn't support auto keyword ?May be I need to upgrade the compiler?

Comment: which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: It depends on the version of GCC you use

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: On window I compile for V10 not 11 ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) is a link to gcc c++ 11 support.  You also need to add -std=c++11 to your command line.

Comment: But how that comes that on Windows I don't use 11 either and "auto" works?